# Make Dygraps chart background grid lighter

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have done the dygraph chart and it is working fine. I need to make the background grid lines lighter which i have marked in the image.

[image: Dygraph Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the [`gridLineColor`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#gridLineColor) option, or the [`gridLineWidth`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#gridLineWidth) option. If you want to have fewer gridlines, you can tweak the [`pixelsPerLabel`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#pixelsPerLabel) setting for the y-axis.